Testing equality of multiple proportions in mixing problems
There are two lakes A (43000 cubic feet) and B (30000 cubic feet). A factory dumps waste matter into both lakes. A measurement yields three types of pollutants a, b, c.
The percentage of the lakes filled with these pollutants are:
Lake A: [%a(A), %b(A), %c(A)] = [8%, 4%, 2%]. Here 8% means that 8% of the entire lake is made of pollutant a.
Lake B: [%a(B), %b(B), %c(B)] = [7%, 5%, 1.5%].
I want to test the null hypothesis that the three proportion are the same, i.e. %a(A)=%a(B), %b(A)=%b(B), %c(A)=%c(B). I need a statistic that does this test.
Note: the test has to be scale-invariant, meaning that if I measure the lakes in cubic feet or cubic inches or cubic meters, I arrive at the same answer. Regular chi-square fails to be scale-invariant.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need information about (a) the measurement error and (b) how these measurements were obtained (relating to how homogeneous the lakes are).  Without both of these, there's nothing (statistically supportable) you can say, because then you have just two different data points and no basis to assess the various possible causes of the difference.
